# Perform action for certain amount of time JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a game and I would like to play an intro picture for 3 seconds and then call the methods to start the game. I have tried using `Thread.sleep` but I know thats probably not a great way and it didnt work. Anyone know a good way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
 ImageView intro = new ImageView(new Image("/Resources/Intro.png"));  

        root.getChildren().add(intro);

        if (startGame) {
        InitializeGame.InitGame();
        InitializeGame.StartGame();
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `PauseTransition`. It's not clear from your code what parts you want to execute after the pause, but something like:

```
ImageView intro = new ImageView(new Image("/Resources/Intro.png"));  

root.getChildren().add(intro);

PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    InitializeGame.InitGame();
    InitializeGame.StartGame();
});
pause.play();
```

Comment: What exactly would that do? Just wait 3 seconds till calling those methods?

Comment: @user7455531 Why don't you try it? It would display `intro` (assuming `root` is in a scene and the scene is in a stage), and then after a three second pause it would call `InitGame` and `StartGame()`.

Comment: @user7455531If that is different to what you want, you need to edit your question to clarify what it is you are looking to do.